# Phpmyadmin cannot connect to mysql: 2054 - Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0 servers is not supported

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've installed new XAMPP, version 1.8.1, it works, but I cannot connect from phpmyadmin to database. Message in error said that I had old mysql database. I downloaded version 5.5 and installed it and I get still this same error. In XAMPP apacha and mysql are started. When I installed mysql I was created password for root and I didn't created second user. Maybe samewhere in phpmyadmin configuration I should change password for the root too ?

Error:

Error

MySQL said: Documentation

## 2054 - Connecting to 3.22, 3.23 & 4.0 servers is not supported

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Thanks

Comment: The most logical explanation would be that you still have an older mySQL server running instead of the 5.5 one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to new server of mysql or change the version of phpmyadmin

Comment: Yes I copy from d/programfiles/mysql to xampp/mysql and run signon.php to login into user add during installation, now it works