# #2054 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

Hi I am Unable to Login to the Wamp Server...

[image]

Please Someone help me out to solve this issue..
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: do user root exists in your database?

Comment: Yes..but without any passwords

Comment: This posts might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643288/phpmyadmin-2054-cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288714/phpmyadmin-cannot-connect-to-mysql-2054-connecting-to-3-22-3-23-4-0-server

Answer (score 0):

Well if you know the 'root' account exists and has no password then leave the password field blank and hit the GO button.